# Printing after typecasting with %d or %i gives unexpected outputs

Tags: c, arrays, string, casting, printf

I am rounding off some values and then printing them. When I use %f option, they are printed correctly, but using the %d or %i option (even after casting the rounded values to int) is giving a weird output, and I am not able to figure the why of it out.

Any help is much appreciated!

When I use %f:

```
i = 0;

while(i < n_shapes)
{
    ll_x[i] = (int)round((ll_x[i] - min_x)/pitch_x);
    ll_y[i] = (int)round((ll_y[i] - min_y)/pitch_y);
    ur_x[i] = (int)round((ur_x[i] - min_x)/pitch_x);
    ur_y[i] = (int)round((ur_y[i] - min_y)/pitch_y);
    printf("%f,%f,%f,%f\n", ll_x[i], ll_y[i], ur_x[i], ur_y[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
115.000000,94.000000,115.000000,101.000000
116.000000,51.000000,117.000000,58.000000
116.000000,60.000000,117.000000,67.000000
116.000000,69.000000,117.000000,75.000000
116.000000,77.000000,117.000000,84.000000
116.000000,86.000000,117.000000,93.000000
116.000000,94.000000,117.000000,101.000000
```

Now, with %d (or %i):

```
i = 0;

while(i < n_shapes)
{
    ll_x[i] = (int)round((ll_x[i] - min_x)/pitch_x);
    ll_y[i] = (int)round((ll_y[i] - min_y)/pitch_y);
    ur_x[i] = (int)round((ur_x[i] - min_x)/pitch_x);
    ur_y[i] = (int)round((ur_y[i] - min_y)/pitch_y);
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", ll_x[i], ll_y[i], ur_x[i], ur_y[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
1079590912,0,6,-1
1078788096,0,5,-1
1079033856,0,6,-1
1079164928,0,6,-1
1079312384,0,6,-1
1079459840,0,6,-1
1079590912,0,6,-1
```

Thank you!

Edit: Yes, I realize that using (int) in the printf gives me the right output. I was curious about the values I got when I didn't do so. What does my output when I use %d without casting inside the printf mean?

Comment: Try casting your variables to `(int)` right in the `printf`. If you have `double`s, and assign to them with a typecast, they will be recast to `double`, so you don't achieve anything beyond rounding.

Comment: Also, if you ever use fortran (in an old/bad way), make sure that your input and output variables to a subroutine (on the caller/callee sides) are the same. Otherwise you can get funky unexpected results just like this one, by misinterpreting the bytes and representation of the variable.

Comment: Compile your application with full warnings on, e.g. for gcc with `-Wall -Wextra`. These warn you about passing incorrect type to the format specifier.

Comment: Show the definitions of `ll_x`, `ll_y`, `ur_x`, `ur_y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. You need to use the correct type specifier.

`printf` cannot verify that the types of parameters that you pass to it for printing match their corresponding format specifiers. The compiler performs type-specific conversions before passing these parameters, so `printf` expects that for each `%f` if would find a `double` (`float` gets converted to `double` as well) and for each `%d` it would find an `int`. Your code passes a `double`-converted value for that `%d` specifier, which causes undefined behavior.

Note that casting a `float` or a `double` expression to `int` before assigning to a `float` or `double` variable does not change the representation of the number. All it does is truncating the fractional part. The representation remains the same. In other words, if you do

```
double x = 12.345;
double y = (int)x;
```

it is the same as

```
double x = 12.345;
double y = (double)((int)x);
```

because in this case the compiler knows the type of variable `y`, and inserts the missing cast for you.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight. The output I get does not have any significance, then, and is just garbage? I was curious because all the values in the first column are very close to each other, and so on with each column. I thought there might be more to this pattern than their just being garbage.

Comment: I think you can think of it as misread Morse code. If I tell you that the message is `--........---..`, but don't tell you the word boundaries, how can you read the message? You can, but it's prone to errors. One mistake is enough to garble the entire message.

Comment: @user2391326 Correct, in this case the output could be considered garbage, because it's your `double`s re-interpreted as `int`s. `double`s use a tricky layout, with upper bits used to hold the exponent, and lower bits used for mantissa. See more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, couldn't they even have different size? Depending on architecture. If so, this seems like an ever stronger deal-breaker to me.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, they could, and very often they are. In fact, it looks like OP's computer uses 64-bit `double`s and 32-bit `int`s.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Suspect your `--........---..` is "message" - one of many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to learn about `gcc` is that you need to turn warnings on explicitly and make them errors using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. These are going to warn you about many useful things if you do not do them exactly right.

Including the format string and wrong argument types as you have here.

I guess the reason why these warning options are not enabled by default is that good-old-perfectly-working-K&R-code would now produce warnings and upset some venerable hackers.